# PowerShell - Filter filenames using pipeline where-object with array of strings

Tags: arrays, powershell, filter

Windows 10
PS 5.1

I am trying to confirm if a filename contains one or more strings. They are not exact matches, so should be able to handle a wildcard, though, usage of wildcards is not necessary if the comparison operator doesn't accept them.
In my scenario, I am iterating through many filenames in a pipeline and filtering filenames using where-object. I've only been able to filter using a single string whereas I haven't been able to filter using an array of strings. I've uploaded my code to github.

https://github.com/ChrisK847/WordSearcher

Here are the key lines of code

```
#Line 29
$FileNameLike = "2016-09", "2016-10" #, "2016-08", "2016-10"

#Line 70
if($FileNameLike -eq ""){$FileNameLike = "*"}elseif($FileNameLike -ne ""){$FileNameLike = $FileNameLike | %{ $_ -replace $_,"*$_*"}} #{$FileNameLike = "*$FileNameLike*"}

#Line 103
Where-Object FullName -like $FileNameLike |
```

The most important line where I'm trying to make the changes is line 103.

I've tried using -in, -match (without using *), -contains, and -like. Neither of them worked on arrays. The Microsoft documentation "about comparison operators" does not contain the word array. I've tried flipping the objects, like "Where-object {$FileNameLike -like $_.FullName} using each of the comparison operators, but that didn't work. The Microsoft Document "About Where-Object" contains one example, but it doesn't work in my situation.

```
#From About Where-Object
Get-Process | where -Property ProcessName -in -Value "Svchost", "TaskHost", "WsmProvHost"
```

In the About Where-Object example, they don't provide an example with wildcards. I do not know the full name of the file before hand, so a wildcard or an operator that performs similarly to an operator with a wildcard is necessary. I only want to list my keywords on line 29.

The directory that I am searching in has 56,000 files, so I need to use the pipeline, or it ends up maxing out my PC's memory.

So that you don't have to create a directory with 56,000 files with various names and create new directories, and so that testing is faster, I have been testing with sample code that should replicate what I'm trying to do. I still haven't had any luck with the simplest of examples

```
cls
$Matches = $null
$keyWords = "3", "r"
$fileNames = "file1","file2","file3"

#$null -ne ($keyWords | ? { $fileNames -match $_ }) #THIS WORKS, BUT DOES NOT CONFORM WITH THE ORDER IN MY SCRIPT.
ForEach($fileName in $fileNames){
    $fileName
    $fileName | ?{$keyWords -contains $_}
    $fileName | ?{$keyWords -like $_}
    $fileName | ?{$keyWords -in $_}
    $fileName | ?{$keyWords -match $_}
    $fileName | ?{$_ -contains $keyWords}
    $fileName | ?{$_ -like $keyWords}
    $fileName | ?{$_ -in $keyWords}
    $fileName | ?{$_ -match $keyWords}
}
```

In the sample code, notice this line
#$null -ne ($keyWords | ? { $fileNames -match $_ })

That works outside of my pipeline where-object Fullname -like $FileNameLike and is the only working example, however, how do I put that inside my where-object line 103?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify multiple patterns with -like operator.  To specify multiple patterns with like you would have to specify multiple expressions separated by -and or -or

```
Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*2016-09*" -or $_.Name -like "*2016-10*"}
```

You can build the expression and then use it as your Where-Object filter.

**(Updated to use scriptblock and not use invoke-expression based on comments - Thank you zelt42)**

```
$FileNameLike = "2016-09", "2016-10" #, "2016-08", "2016-10"

$filter = if (!$FileNameLike) {
    [scriptblock]::Create('$_.Name -like "*"')
}
else {
    $output = foreach ($filter in $FileNameLike) {
        "`$_.Name -like '*$filter*'"
    }
    [scriptblock]::Create($output -join ' -or ')
}

#Line 103
Where-Object -FilterScript $filter |
```

Alternatively, the -match operator utilizes regular expression so you could do something like this instead

```
Where-Object {$_.Name -match "2016-09|2016-10"}
```

Build your regex pattern and use that in your Where-Object filter block

```
$FileNameLike = "2016-09", "2016-10" #, "2016-08", "2016-10"

$regexPattern = if (!$FileNameLike) {
    ".*"
} else {
    ($FileNameLike | % {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
}

Where-Object {$_.name -match $regexPattern }
```

Comment: In the first example you are missing a space between `$_.Name` and `-like`. Instead of assigning a string that contains the script, I suggest to simply return a script block like this: `$filter = if(!$FileNameLike) { [ScriptBlock]{ $_.Name -like '*' } }`. The cast isn't really necessary but IMO makes the code more readable.

Comment: ditto to @zett42, but also when building the regex filter, I think you should use `[regex]::Escape($FileNameLike) -join "|"` because filenames tend to contain characters with special meaning in regex.

Comment: Thanks @zett42.  Fixed the spacing issue.  I would update the first to scriptblock but not sure how to do the same for the 2nd where I'm building up the expression.  Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: You don't need the expression with `-or` operators. Something like this should work: `foreach ($filter in $FileNameLike) { if( $_.Name -like "*$filter*" ){ $true; break } }`

Comment: Also I don't think you need multiple script blocks. One should suffice: `$filter = { if(...) {...} else {...} }`. I this case I would not use the `[ScriptBlock]` type at all, because `$script = { ... }` is a common pattern and the curly brackets make it easy to identify.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to confirm if a filename contains one or more strings.

Multiple search strings represent multiple queries. I suggest writing them in test cases.

```
$location = "C:\lab"

Get-ChildItem -Path $location -Recurse -File | 
  Where-Object {
    switch -Wildcard ($_.Name)
    {
      '*2016-08*' {$true; Break}
      '*2016-09*' {$true; Break}
     #'*2016-10*' {$true; Break}
     #'*2016-11*' {$true; Break}
      default     {$false}
    }
  } | 
  Select-Object -Property Name 


PS > .\Stack Overflow Demo.ps1

Name
----
report 2016-09-01.txt
```

---

> I only want to list my keywords on line 29.

It is possible to generate code from a variable, but this obscures your intent and is nonstandard.

**If you accept user input, this makes your script vulnerable to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection)**.

```
$location = "C:\lab"

$FileNameLike = "*2016-08*", "*2016-09*" , "*2016-10*", "*2016-11*"

$beginning = @"
Get-ChildItem -Path `$location -Recurse -File | 
  Where-Object {
    switch -Wildcard (`$_.Name)
    {

"@

$middle = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

foreach ($myString in $FileNameLike)
{  [void]$middle.AppendLine( "      '$myString' {`$true; Break}" )  }

$end = @"
      default     {`$false}
    }
  } | 
  Select-Object -Property Name 
"@

$myScript = $beginning + $middle.ToString() + $end 

Invoke-Expression -Command $myScript




PS > .\dynamic code generation 02.ps1

Name
----
report 2016-09-01.txt
report 2016-10-01.txt
```

### Explanation

```
$location = "C:\lab"
```

Save the path to the folder being scanned.

---

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $location -Recurse -File |
```

List the contents of `$location`. Scan subfolders with `-Recurse`. Limit output to `-File`s. Begin a pipeline `|`.

---

```
  Where-Object {
  } |
```

[Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) returns all objects for which the script block statement is true.

Continue the pipeline `|`

---

```
    switch -Wildcard ($_.Name)
    {
      '*2016-08*' {$true; Break}
      '*2016-09*' {$true; Break}
     #'*2016-10*' {$true; Break}
     #'*2016-11*' {$true; Break}
      default     {$false}
    }
```

*Use a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) to handle multiple If statements*.

`-Wildcard` indicates that the condition is a wildcard string. The comparison is case-insensitive.

Optionally, you might use the `-CaseSensitive` switch.

[$_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#_) contains the current object in the pipeline. You can use this variable in commands that perform an action on every object or on selected objects in a pipeline.

`$_.Name` is the file name of the current file being processed.

```
'*2016-08*' {$true; Break}
```

Each case consists of a *wildcard string* and an *action*. Define the string including [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards).

Remember that [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) returns all objects for which the script block statement is true. So, when one of our strings matches the file name, use the *action* to return `$true` and then [Break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch). The `Break` keyword stops processing and exits the Switch statement.

If none of the strings match, output `$false`.

---

```
Select-Object -Property Name
```

Output the `Name`s of the files that matched.

---

```
PS > .\Stack Overflow Demo.ps1

Name
----
report 2016-09-01.txt
```

Run the script and show the result.

#### Dynamic Script Explanation

```
$FileNameLike = "*2016-08*", "*2016-09*" , "*2016-10*", "*2016-11*"
```

Store the search strings in an array including their wildcards.

---

```
$beginning = @"
"@

$middle = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

$end = @"
"@

$myScript = $beginning + $middle.ToString() + $end 

Invoke-Expression -Command $myScript
```

If we are going to generate dynamic code, we will need a string and [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression).

We can dynamically generate test cases based on the value of `$FileNameLike` and store the result in `$middle`.

`$beginning` and `$end` are static strings.

---

```
$beginning = @"
Get-ChildItem -Path `$location -Recurse -File | 
  Where-Object {
    switch -Wildcard (`$_.Name)
    {

"@
```

Use a double-quoted [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#here-strings) to define `$beginning`

Because we're using double quotes, escape any dollar signs with `

Note that embedded variables like `$location` will work as intended because expressions are evaluated and run in the [current scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression).

Leave a trailing newline to prepare for the `$middle`.

---

```
$middle = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

foreach ($myString in $FileNameLike)
{  [void]$middle.AppendLine( "      '$myString' {`$true; Break}" )  }
```

Use [StringBuilder](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-11-20-Powershell-StringBuilder/) as the container for your dynamically generated code. StringBuilder saves us the cost of copying strings in memory.

Use [AppendLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline?view=net-5.0) to add the string *and* a newline character to the string we are building.

Cast the method call to `[void]` to discard output from the method.

Use [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach) to iterate over each value of `$FileNameLike`

Note that `$myString` is not escaped. This is what allows the values in `$FileNameLike` to be introduced to the code dynamically.

---

```
$myScript = $beginning + $middle.ToString() + $end
```

To output a string from a StringBuilder object, use the `ToString()` method.

---

```
Invoke-Expression -Command $myScript
```

Once the command has been dynamically generated, use [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) to execute the contents of the string.

**Using `Invoke-Expression` to execute a string represents a security risk**. Any user input that appears inside the string can do or delete anything the underlying user can.

---

You mentioned that there are 56,000 files to process. If you are able to use [PowerShell 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/powershell/9mz1snwt0n5d), you might be able to make use of [ForEach-Object -Parallel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) to increase the processing speed. The [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1#examples) discuss some of the coding practices you will need to use -Parallel.

If you want a fast and reliable way to search files, you might like [X1 Search](https://www.x1.com/products/x1-search/).

If you choose to use regex instead, note that [[regex]::Escape()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0)

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $, ., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes.

For example, bracket `]` and brace `}` are not escaped. This might not affect this use case. Please understand the limitations of [regex]::Escape() and be prepared to test cases.

---

Here is a demonstration using `-FilterScript` to hijack the shell.

````
$location = "C:\lab" 

$FileNameLike = "'; Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList `"-Command ```{```"Hello```"```}`" -NoNewWindow; '", "2016-10" #, "2016-08", "2016-10"

$filter = if (!$FileNameLike) {
    [scriptblock]::Create('$_.Name -like "*"')
}
else {
    $output = foreach ($filter in $FileNameLike) {
        "`$_.Name -like '*$filter*'"
    }
    [scriptblock]::Create($output -join ' -or ')
}

#Line 103
Get-ChildItem -Path $location -Recurse -File | Where-Object -FilterScript $filter




PS > .\proof of concept.ps1

    Directory: C:\lab

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---            3/5/2021  7:45 AM              0 report 2016-09-01.txt
-a---            3/5/2021  7:45 AM              0 report 2016-10-01.txt
-a---            3/5/2021  7:45 AM              0 report 2017-09-01.txt

PS > Hello
HelloHello
````